# Redux: affecting two state keys

Tags: reactjs, redux

everyone!

I am new in Redux and I try to build weather app. My state is looks like:

```js
const state = {
  cities: [],
  selectedCity: {}
}
```

I have city reducer and selectedCity reducer. When user delete all cities except last I want to force selectedCity to that one. How can I affect selectedCity when changing cities? ( in this case delete from cities array )

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do is automatically, you will either need to modify the selectedCity when you change cities array, or use a conditional.

`cities.length === 1 ? cities[0] : selectedCity` in the your render function or wherever you need it.

**Edit:**

What you are trying to do, active data being an extended async-gathered version of the one stored in cities, requires side-effects.

A clean way of doing so would be something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.cityChangeHandler = this.cityChangeHandler.bind(this);

cityChangeHandler(city) {
  changeActive(city); // That's an action, which will update the Redux store.
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>{this.props.selectedCity && selectedCity.name}</div>
  );
```

```
function mapStateProps(state) {
  selectedCity: state.selectedCity,
  cities: state.cities,
}
```

Comment: <CitiesList /> and <ActiveCity /> are different components. First uses cities state key, second uses activeCity state key. Each knows nothing about another

Comment: in the end you have reducer which can manage both even if you send action to do something with one of them

Comment: @Dmitriy In your mapStateToProps you can pass any redux variable you need. You shouldn't need to modify both to notify two different components.

Comment: @Kejt did you mean result of combineReducers?

Comment: @zurfyx is it correct solution to pass cities key to activeCity component?

Comment: @Dmitriy that's another thing. https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/693 (see his mapStateToProps)

Comment: @Dmitriy you can pass it as props. That's a correct solution as well. You generally want to use Redux when you present you'll need that data elsewhere that would cause too much props passing through nesting.

Comment: @Dmitriy that's a great example project if you want to check about best practices https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/containers/HomePage/index.js

Comment: in my cities key i have only names and ids, rather in activeCity i have API response with full weather info for activeCity. That is why if we have only one city in cities key we should invoke changeCity() action and pass particular city id to it from cities key. Response of async changeCity() action will be activeCity key for my state. Any minds? =)

Comment: @Dmitriy see the edit. That's a way of resolving your problem (probably the one you would use in a big project). Another possibility, which you can even do without Redux, would be to create a component on top of them, that does the async job then passing the data as props. Since you always require to gather that extra data for every city, my first reply (before the dit) would probably not be the most ideal.

Comment: @zurfyx i have async action in order to get cities list from API, and then, when clicking on one of them we do another async action to fetch clicked city weather. activeCity filled when we click on city from "cities" key. When i click delete near the city from "cities" key i dispatch action "DELETE_CITY" and catch inside cities reducer. Where i can dispatch action if after deleting only one city left on cities key?

Comment: @Dmitriy do not fetch in this case, but still dispatch `selectedCity` with no city (you can control this inside your reducer). Once again, that an opinionated question, there are many correct ways of doing so.

Comment: @zurfyx i found best solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42100974/5273160

Answer (score 0):

Wow! I found the answer!

I forgot, that in async action except "dispatch" we pass getState method as second argument in thunk middleware.

For example:

```
export default function thunkMiddleware({ dispatch, getState }) {
    return next => action => {
        typeof action === 'function' ?
            action(dispatch, getState) :
            next(action);
    }
}
```

**That is solution:** in action, after sync dispatching DELETE_CITY we check getState().cities length. If it equal 1 - dispatch CHOOSE_CITY action witch that city.

For example:

```
export function deleteCity(city) {
    return function(dispatch, getState) {
        dispatch({
            type: CITY_DELETE,
            payload: city
        })

        var currentCitiesLength = getState().cities.length;
        if(currentCitiesLength == 1) {
            dispatch(selectCity(getState().cities[0]));
        } else if(currentCitiesLength == 0) {
            // Pass null to clean selectedCity
            dispatch(selectCity(null));
        }
    }
}
```